# Terraform version 0.9.6 support spot fleet tags

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform

Using Terraform 0.9.6 I get this error when I try to create spot fleet using the code below, but when I use 
v0.11.7, it works. Terraform doc is [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/spot_fleet_request.html). My question is how can I determine if this is due to lack of v0.9.6 features or if I'm using the syntax incorrectly. How can I find this out?

I need to make the sport fleet resource tags work with v0.9.6.

Error:

```
* aws_spot_fleet_request.cheap_compute: launch_specification.0: invalid or unknown key: tags
```

Code:

```
# Request a Spot fleet
resource "aws_spot_fleet_request" "cheap_compute" {
  iam_fleet_role      = "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/aws-service-role/spotfleet.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForEC2SpotFleet"
  spot_price          = "0.03"
  allocation_strategy = "diversified"
  target_capacity     = 2
  valid_until         = "2018-07-21T20:44:20Z"

  launch_specification {
    instance_type     = "t2.micro"
    ami               = "ami-1853ac65"
    spot_price        = "0.777"
    availability_zone = "us-east-1a"
    key_name        = "${var.key_name}"

    tags {
      Name = "spot-fleet-example"}
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for tags in `aws_spot_fleet_request` was added in the **terraform-provider-aws** in [`1.2.0`](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#120-october-31-2017). This was almost 5 months after the release of Terraform `0.9.6`. At that time of `0.9.6` providers were shipped with **Terraform**. They later moved to shipping independently as part of [`0.10.0`](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0100-august-2-2017) a few months later. You'll need a newer version to get tag support.

Comment: The 0.9.6 seems to work for resource "aws_instance" and tags. It just doesn't seem to work for spot fleet and tags. Your response seem to imply tags in general?

Comment: Just spot fleet tagging, clarified answer.